# Адаптация кода более поздних версий Joomla для Joomla 1.5

Tags: joomla, php

Здравствуйте!

Попросили помочь с версией сайта для слабовидящих. Сайт на joomla 1.5.

Нашел [ветку](http://joomlaforum.ru/index.php/topic,297453.0.html) форума, где ведется обсуждение, и форумчане уже адаптировали шаблон к joomla, за что огромное спасибо им!

Вся беда в том, что версия моей joomla ниже, чем предложенный плагин и шаблон. Шаблон адаптировал - с ним проблем нет. Но к нему есть еще плагин, который запоминает состояние, какой шаблон используется.

Оригинальный код плагина:

```
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die;

class plgSystemTemplateSwitcher extends JPlugin
    {
        function onAfterInitialise()
            {
                $input = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
                $session = JFactory::getSession();
                $template = $input->getCmd( 'template', '' );
                if ( $template !== '' ) {
                $session->set( 'templateChanged', $template );
                }
                if ( $session->get( 'templateChanged', '' )!== '' ) {
                $input->set( 'template', $session->get( 'templateChanged', '' ) );
                }
            }
    }
```

Немножко подправлен для версии 1.5:

```
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die;

class plgSystemTemplateSwitcher extends JPlugin
    {
        function onAfterInitialise()
            {
                            $input = JFactory::getApplication()->input; // и вот проблема.
                $session = JFactory::getSession();
                $template = JRequest::getVar('template');
                if ( $template !== '' ) {
                    $session->set( 'templateChanged', $template );
                }
                if ( $session->get( 'templateChanged', '' )!== '' ) {
                                    //Ругается, что нет такого метода set()
                    $input->set( 'template', $session->get( 'templateChanged', '' ) );
                }
            }
    }
```

Выдает ошибку:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function set() on a non-object
```

С Joomla сталкиваюсь впервые, может, кто знает аналог JFactory::getApplication()->input для версии 1.5?

Comment: Нет там шаблона на форуме. Есть 2.5, но он коряво работает на 1.5 версии. Не знает он директивы TPL_ACCESSIBILITY_VIEW_SETTINGS и прочее

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разобрался.

```
$input->set( 'template', $session->get( 'templateChanged', '' ) );
```

заменить на:

```
JRequest::setVar('template', $session->get('templateChanged'));
```

Comment: Привет, можешь скинуть шаблон для 1.5 джумлы на docx_@mail.ru? буду премного благодарен

Comment: Привет. Нет, шаблона не осталось.Можно забрать его на форуме http://joomlaforum.ru/index.php/topic,297453.0.html

Только нужно подправить xml файл. Мне надоело его править и я просто загрузил все через FTP в папку тем. Там же можно взять и код рабочего плагина для переключения темы адаптированного для версии 1.5